# ACTION_SEND attached file doesnt show in instagram

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram, intentfilter, android-fileprovider

I want to share a picture from my gallery and I can open chooser for it. Picture doesnt shown When I click story button. Instagram intent open but only black screen in it. There is an error just story mode.

```
 val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    share.type = type

    val media = File(mediaPath)
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), media)
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. Also, add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

Comment: I dont get it how can I use concrete mimetype, And there is no problem video or other apps. there is an error only in instagram story mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess instagram accepted only jpg format for story. I convert my picture format and problem solver.